# Where do you view the output from airflow jobs

Tags: airflow

In the airflow tutorial, the `BashOperator`s have output (via `echo`). If the task runs in the scheduler, where do you view the output? Is there a console or something? I'm sure I'm just not looking in the right place.

Comment: If run with the test parameter in console -> in the console. If run within the webserver -> in the DAGs log page on the webpage. It is a bit hard to suggest what to do without knowing your environment and the steps you are doing.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Like @tobi6 said, you can view the output from your DAG runs in your webserver or in your console depending on the environment.

To do so in your webserver:

1. Select the DAG you just ran and enter into the `Graph View`.
2. Select the task in that DAG that you want to view the output of.
3. In the following popup, click `View Log`.
4. In the following log, you can now see the output or it will give you the link to a page where you can view the output (if you were using Databricks for example, the last line might be "INFO - View run status, Spark UI, and logs at domain.cloud.databricks.com#job/jobid/run/1").

If you want to view the logs from your run, you do so in your `airflow_home` directory.

- Information from Airflow official documentation on logs below:

> Users can specify a logs folder in airflow.cfg. By default, it is in the AIRFLOW_HOME directory.
>
> In addition, users can supply a remote location for storing logs and log backups in cloud storage. At this time, Amazon S3 and Google
>   Cloud Storage are supported. To enable this feature, airflow.cfg must
>   be configured as in this example:
>
> ```
> [core]
> # Airflow can store logs remotely in AWS S3 or Google Cloud Storage. Users
> # must supply a remote location URL (starting with either 's3://...' or
> # 'gs://...') and an Airflow connection id that provides access to the storage
> # location.
> remote_base_log_folder = s3://my-bucket/path/to/logs
> remote_log_conn_id = MyS3Conn
> # Use server-side encryption for logs stored in S3
> encrypt_s3_logs = False
> Remote logging uses an existing Airflow connection to read/write logs. If you don’t have a connection properly setup, this will fail.
> ```
>
> In the above example, Airflow will try to use S3Hook('MyS3Conn').
>
> In the Airflow Web UI, local logs take precedance over remote logs. If local logs can not be found or accessed, the remote logs will
>   be displayed. Note that logs are only sent to remote storage once a
>   task completes (including failure). In other words, remote logs for
>   running tasks are unavailable. Logs are stored in the log folder as
>   {dag_id}/{task_id}/{execution_date}/{try_number}.log.

Comment: For webserver view, did not work for me - probably the UI has changed since the answer. For the logs in `airflow_home` directory - that worked.

Comment: @davneetnarang what version of airflow are you using? I can check it out and update the answer with different versions.

Comment: Using 2.0.1. Thanks.

Comment: Just saw the answer by @akki and realised that I am supposed to click on the square boxes which denote the task-run and not the circles in the graph which denote the task. Apologies.

Comment: @davneetnarang Check out my answer for airflow 2

Comment: how can we see on_failure_callback DAG calling function logs? It will not come in Task logs.

Answer (score 13):

If a task is in Airflow, here is how to find its logs in the web UI:

1. Click on the name of the task's DAG

[image]

2. Click on the task run
   [image]
3. Click on "View Log" button in the pop-up that opens

[image]

4. The logs page will open up (one needs to keep refreshing it to see logs in real-time).

[image]

Comment: I think it is the same as @zack mentioned but I had the pictures ready so I posted it anyway in case someone finds it useful.

Comment: Nice to have the screenshots, maybe add which version of airflow you took them on?

Comment: Good point. I can't confirm for sure but I think it'd be v1.10.3.

Answer (score 6):

In Airflow 2 to view the logs:

0. Open a dag
1. Click on the square(which represents a single task run; square is red if failed, green if success) shown against a task. This opens details to the right.
2. Click on the "Log" button on the right details tab.

[image]